# Azure devops connection to d365 business central

Tags: api, azure-devops, dynamics-365

We are trying to integrate azure devops with d365 business central for billing purposes. Do you have any api that works to pull the tickets information in devops to business central?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft will release API for continuous delivery of the Business Central apps via Azure DevOps services in the future. Currently some of the functionality described in this release plan has not been released.

The API can be used for the following operations:

- Make major, minor, and hotfix app updates available to customers for
  installation from the Business Central administration center. You
  make the updates available by uploading them to the FAME App
  Repository. The new app versions will then be available on the Manage
  Apps page of the Business Central administration center.
- Retrieve the list of the customers' environments that have your app
  installed.
- Schedule the automatic deployment of the app hotfixes for their
  customers' environments.

For details , please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365-release-plan/2020wave1/dynamics365-business-central/api-continuous-delivery-appsource-apps-via-azure-devops-services).